# SQL UNION ALL query returning all Null values in date field

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, null, union-all

I am trying to split one `datefield` column into three target columns, depending on a `status` column:

My `table1` is as follows:

```
**id    status    DateField**
   1     A       1/5/2018
   2     B       1/6/2018
   3     C       1/7/2018
```

So I am trying to convert this data to the following format (Timestamps tracking when an id entered a certain stage)

```
id    Timestamp_A  Timestamp_B    Timestamp_C
1      1/5/2018     Null           Null
2.     Null         1/6/2018       Null
3.     Null         Null           1/7/2018
```

I used the following query to get the desired results

```
SELECT id, status,
 CAST( DATEFIELD AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_A",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_B",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_C"
FROM table 1
WHERE status='A'

UNION ALL

SELECT id, status,
 CAST( DATEFIELD AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_B",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_A",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_C"
FROM table 1
WHERE status='B'

UNION ALL

SELECT id, status,
 CAST( DATEFIELD AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_C",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_A",
 CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS "Timestamp_B"
FROM table 1
WHERE status='C'
```

Although each query works individually, when I use UNION ALL only the first query seems to work with respect to datefields i.e only Timestamp_A is populated with the correct values, while Timestamps B and C are all Nulls.

```
id    Timestamp_A  Timestamp_B    Timestamp_C
1      1/5/2018     Null           Null
2.       Null       Null           Null
3.       Null       Null           Null
```

Any input or direction on why this is happening?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Postgres. I am connecting it to tableau and using custom SQL to change the layout

Comment: The issue is that your columns are not in order. You have to keep the order the same between each code block in the union

Comment: oh that makes sense!thanks.So timestamps should be in order.Let me try that

Comment: worked thanks a ton!

Comment: Great, I'm glad. Since you're new, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of your columns is the issue. You have to keep the order the same... But then again you don't really need the unions at all:

```
SELECT id
    , CASE WHEN DateField = '1/5/2018' THEN DateField END AS TimeStampA
    , CASE WHEN DateField = '1/6/2018' THEN DateField END AS TimeStampB
    , CASE WHEN DateField = '1/7/2018' THEN DateField END AS TimeStampC
FROM t
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT id, status,
       (CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN datefield END) AS Timestamp_A,
       (CASE WHEN status = 'B' THEN datefield END) AS Timestamp_B,
       (CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN datefield END) AS Timestamp_C
FROM t;
```